# How to modify categories text size in BOKEH bar charts?

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

I am unsuccessfully trying to modify the size of the text of the different categories (text highlighted in yellow) in a BOKEH bar-chart.

[image]

I would be really grateful if somebody knows how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to modify the text size of the `CategoricalAxis` which is `below` the figure object (usually first item at position 0).

To modify the text size for groups, use this line.

```
p.below[0].group_text_font_size = '13px'
```

In the same way you can set multiple other styling options, like the `axis_label_text_font_size` or the `major_label_text_font_size` and many other. To see how it works, look at the example below.

**Demonstration**

Following the example from bokeh about [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories) the output looks like this:

[image: before text size modification]

Now you can do some changes for the text below the x-axis.

```
p.below[0].group_text_font_size = '16px'
p.below[0].group_text_font_style = 'normal'
p.below[0].group_text_color = 'black'
p.below[0].major_label_text_font_size = '14px'
p.below[0].major_label_text_color = 'black'
```

This will set

1. a new font size for groups (`'16px'`) and labels (`'14px'`),
2. a new font color for groups and labels (here `'black'`) and
3. a new font style to the groups (here `'normal'`).

The figure looks now like this:
[image: after text size modification]