# How to set the x axis group names font size in Bokeh?

Tags: python, graph, bar-chart, bokeh, stacked-chart

I'm trying to set the x axis font size for a nested barplot  with bokeh but i can't find the right way (or any way) to do it . I been using pretty much the template for the fruits graph in bokeh gallery with a few variations.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_dodged.html

if I use `p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "12pt"` it just changes the x_ticks but not the group labels. Also, using `p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "12pt"` does not seem to change anything. Im quite lost at this point.

Here is my code, thanks!

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bar_stacked.html")
#output_notebook()

diagnosis = ["one", "two", "three"]
datos = ["I", "D", "C"]

data = {'Diagnosis' : diagnosis,
        'I'   : [332, 272, 187],
        'D'   : [600, 302, 174],
        'C'   : [859, 552, 263]}

palette = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

x = [(diag, dato) for diag in diagnosis for dato in datos]
counts = sum(zip(data['I'], data['D'], data['C']), ()) # like an hstack

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=450,
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source,line_color="white",
       fill_color=factor_cmap('x', palette=palette, factors=datos, start=1, end=2) )

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

p.title.text = "Data available by Diagnosis"
p.title.text_font_size = "14pt"
p.title.align = 'center'
p.title.text_font ="ubuntu"

p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "12pt"
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "9pt"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3/4
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font = "ubuntu"
#p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_style = "bold"

p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "12pt"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font = "ubuntu"
#p.yaxis.axis_label_text_color = "black"

#p.legend.label_text_font_size = '30pt'

show(p)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify categories text size in BOKEH bar charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206616/how-to-modify-categories-text-size-in-bokeh-bar-charts)

Comment: Hi @mosc9575. Yes it does! I didn't find that answer when I searched for the solution! I guess I 'll have to learn how to search this kind od ulta specific thinghs! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at all properties of axis [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html), you can find property `group_text_font_size`.

That is exactly that you are looking for.

So, the code will be:

```
p.xaxis.group_text_font_size = "18pt" # for example
```